# Redirect to URL with umlauts or accents via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, utf-8, internationalization, idn

To redirect to a new URL that contains diacritics via .htaccess, what is the correct and safe way?

- Can I somehow set the .htaccess file to UTF-8 and just use the non-ASCII characters, e.g.:
  `redirect 301 / http://www.bücher.ch/`
- Need I use the ACE string instead,  e.g.:
  `redirect 301 / http://www.xn--bcher-kva.ch/`
- Is urlencode the way to go? I tried the following without success:
  `redirect 301 / http://www.b%C3%BCcher.ch/`

For context, the following page on [internationalized domain names (IDN)](https://www.nic.ch/reg/cm/wcm-page/faqs/idn.jsp?lid=en) has a section about the technical solution to include accents and umlauts in domains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the domain part, you must use ASCII Compatible Encoding (ACE).
In the rest of the URL, you use urlencode. So, in .htaccess…

`http://www.bücher.ch/schöne/`

…needs to be written as…

`http://www.xn--bcher-kva.ch/sch%C3%B6ne/`